# CSV file replacement in a Map Tour- Story Map

Tags: arcgis-online, story-map

On the Map Tour story app, I imported a CSV file. Worked great! However, I want to put a *different* one up there. There seems to be no way to delete that without deleting each individual picture. If I try to import a different CSV, it says "CSV file empty" which they aren't. What should I do?